# How to use private keys from the Android keystore in Bouncy Castle

Tags: android, bouncycastle

I'm using Bouncy Castle to produce and consume PKCS#7/CMS `EnvelopedData` and `SignedData` values. How can I get BC to use the private keys in the [Android keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) when signing or decrypting? Note I can't retrieve the private keys because that's the whole point of the keystore system.

For example, when I'm decrypting an `EnvelopedData` value for a `KeyTransRecipientInfo` recipient, I'd have to [pass the private key to `org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient`](https://github.com/relaycorp/relaynet-jvm/blob/22f85cb851ee8c1dc1c1e1e2731420bedc4cd69d/src/main/kotlin/tech/relaycorp/relaynet/wrappers/cms/EnvelopedData.kt#L139). And when I have to sign a `SignedData` value, I'd have to [pass the private key to `org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.build()`](https://github.com/relaycorp/relaynet-jvm/blob/22f85cb851ee8c1dc1c1e1e2731420bedc4cd69d/src/main/kotlin/tech/relaycorp/relaynet/wrappers/cms/SignedData.kt#L44). How can I do either when the private key never leaves the Android Keystore?

I'm tempted to say this isn't possible, since I haven't found anything that suggests this is possible. That's why I'm checking here.

In case it's relevant, the `EnvelopedData` values will have `KeyTransRecipientInfo` or `KeyAgreeRecipientInfo` recipients.

I guess that failing this, the second best approach would be to create a master (symmetric) key to keep the asymmetric keys [encrypted at rest](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data).

Comment: There is no reason why Bouncycastle can't *use* keys in the Android keystore in general. It depends on what you're doing. In no case can the key material be removed from the android keystore. Bouncycastle includes a provider that fits into the Java Cryptography framework as well as a proprietary API that doesn't. You would need to be more specific.

Comment: I just added a paragraph to call out the BC classes/methods that get the private keys when decrypting/signing. If that's not enough, I'd appreciate it if you told what exactly is missing from the OP to tell whether/how to use BC to use the private keys in the Android Keystore.

Comment: I have no experience in the Android KeyStore provider, but from the doc I quickly went through (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) it seems it works a bit like a PKCS11 interface. You get a pointer on the private key, but can never extract it from the keystore and all crypto operations are made on a dedicated processing unit. Practically speaking, you should load the key entry by specifying its related alias then call whatever crypto operations on this entry.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the code you provided. I believe that the issue is that you're not loading key entries, but trying to manipulate PrivateKey objects directly.

A standard approach is to:

1. load the keystore

> ```
> KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
> ```

2. get the private key entry from the keystore:

> ```
> ProtectionParameter params = null; //some protection parameters...
> KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("alias", params);
> ```

Comment: Thanks @veebee, but how do I get BouncyCastle to use that `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry` instance? For example, when I'm signing, I have to use `org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder`, and having seen the source code, it only supports `PrivateKey` instances. I can't imagine `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey()` would work here because that'd imply a serious vulnerability in the Android Keystore, as I'd be getting hold of the private key.